# Логирование Morgan.js

Tags: node.js, express, консоль

**В какой системе исчисления morgan.js логирует время?** 
Вот например, 14.257. Это с холодного старта. Но явно не прошло полных  14 секунд.

Логирование в консоль*

POST /signin 401 14.257 ms - 42

GET /signout 304 1.589 ms - -

GET /signout 304 3.059 ms - -

GET /signout 304 2.769 ms - -

GET /signout 304 0.968 ms - -

GET /signout 304 1.068 ms - -

Comment: Разве это не время обработки запроса?

Comment: @MiMEKiZ Дак логонирование называется. Можно сказать что время  обработки запроса. Суть не поменяется.